# how can i make a selection between two card views

Tags: java, android, android-studio, material-design, android-cardview

I have two card views and I want to make a selection between them. This is my code but it does not work

```
    cvTruck = view.findViewById(R.id.cv_chooseTransportationVehicle_truck);
    cvMotorcycle = view.findViewById(R.id.cv_chooseTransportationVehicle_motorcycle);

    cvTruck.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        cvTruck.setStrokeWidth(10);
        cvTruck.setStrokeColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.captainBikeColorPrimary));
        cvMotorcycle.setStrokeWidth(0);
        cvMotorcycle.setStrokeColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    });

    cvMotorcycle.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        cvMotorcycle.setStrokeWidth(10);
        cvMotorcycle.setStrokeColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.captainBikeColorPrimary));
        cvTruck.setStrokeWidth(0);
        cvTruck.setStrokeColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    });
```

when i click to each of them other card does not change and both of them get the border

[image: this is result of my code]

Comment: Did you try using a boolean?

Comment: For example, try a private boolean isClicked, then use if statement inside onClicklistener

Comment: that's not work

when i click on each of card views I want the other one border to gone